# Only allow one file to be redirected to stdin

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line

I am currently writing a C++ program with usage:

```
[prog]  - - - - - - - - - - - - read from stdin
[prog] [filename]   - - - - - - will test and open file
[prog] < [filename]   - - - - - will redirect the filename to stdin
```

I have written code to catch too many arguments, and everything works, except that if a user tries

```
[prog] < [filename] [filename]
```

it will open the second filename.

How do I prevent this case from happening.  Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Simply put, you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that a process can look at to authoritatively conclude whether or not the shell explicitly redirected the process's standard input away from the default.

But a process can make a very educated guess when running on a POSIX platform, where [isatty()](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/isatty.3.html) returns an indication whether the given file descriptor is attached to an interactive terminal. So, you can check if `isatty(0)` (standard input file descriptor #0); if so this means that the process's standard input is still attached to interactive keyboard input, and has not been redirected.

This is not 100% foolproof. It is still possible to go through an elaborate song-and-dance routine, and using a pseudo-tty device attach a pipe to a process's standard input that's indistinguishable from an interactive terminal, to the process, but the input really comes from some other source, but this is very rare, and for your typical garden-variety application, `isatty()` should be sufficient. So, your `main()` can check `isatty(0)`, and if so it's a very good indication that the input has not been redirected.

Note, however, if `isatty(0)` is not true, the standard input is likely redirected, but additional sleuthing will be required to figure out if it's a pipe, or a plain file, or something else, perhaps.

So, your overall gameplan here is: check if your `argv` specifies a filename. If so, if `isatty(0)`, then you've got two likely input files to deal with.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to check out isatty() and test it, I hadn't heard of it.

Comment: This works for my needs, but I will take into consideration that it is not a guarantee this will be 100% foolproof.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I prevent this case from happening. Thanks for your consideration.

I don't think you can prevent this. A user can easily circumvent any such restrictions you might want to impose by using other tools to concatenate files. For examples, the user can easily use:

```
cat filename1 filename2 | program
```

Comment: The answer by Sam Varshavchik lets me make a test case to prevent the simple case I described, but thanks for this info. I will test this out and see what happens. It is a school project, so I probably don't need to guard against the case you described, but if I can let my instructor know I tested for these special cases, I'm sure that would not be a bad thing.