# input redirection file name c++

Tags: c++, cin, getline, io-redirection

I have several arguments to my program and an input file being redirected. i am parsing the arguments (using argc and argv) and the file (using cin). However, I am not able to display the name of the redirected file. For instance, the arguments are-

```
./procsim -r 2 -f 4 -j 3 -k 2 -l 1 < gcc.100k.trace
```

and my code to parse the arguments is -

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
    if (argv[i][0] == '-')
        {
        if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-r"))
        {
            if (i < argc - 1)
            {
                pipeline_parameters[count++] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
                R = atoi(argv[i+1]);
                i = i+1;
            }
        }

        else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-f"))
        {
            if (i < argc - 1)
            {
                pipeline_parameters[count++] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
                F = atoi(argv[i+1]);
                i = i+1;
            }
        }
```

and to parse the file, I use cin -

```
 string line;

while (getline( cin, line))
{
address_arr.push_back(line);
}
```

I want to read the fie name, which is gcc.100k.trace here.  how do i do that?
P.S. - I have tried parsing through the arguments, but I'm not able to find it!

Edit: 
**address_arr** is a vector of int. **pipeline_parameters** is an array of int of  length 5, to store the arguments. ***R*** and ***F*** are global variables which store the arguments as well.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as there is information missing from your example, e.g., what is pipeline_parameters or address_arr?

Comment: I don't think you can retrieve the name of the file whose contents were redirected to `stdin`. Take a look at [this answer to another SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42382373/434551). It may lead you to find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly cannot do it using `argc` and `argv`.  If there is any hope at all, it may be to call `getppid()` to get your shell's PID, then read `/proc/PPID/fd` or `proc/PPID/fdinfo` and see what files are open there.

This will be a huge nasty hack, and has no place in a production application.  There's probably not a good enough reason why you'd need to do this, and no other program in the wild does it.